# Is two copies of the same data stored on a RAID 1 array considered a "backup"

Tags: backup

Since I got/built my computer I've been working towards improving my backup situation and my planned setup goes something like this:

**My PC**: 240 GB SSD
**Backup Array**: 1TB RAID1, incremental time machine backup of PC, will be plugged into PC most of the time
**Archive Array**: 500GB RAID1

Since a common rule of backups that I have read about is to *always have at least two copies of your data* (and yes im aware that *RAID does not count as a backup*), I want to be able to have a way to back up my "archive" of stuff, AKA the stuff that I don't really need on my computer immediately, such as old projects, last years school assignments and years-old photos; stuff I still want to keep but don't have space to store on my PC.

However, taking these files off my PC also means that they aren't being backed up with time machine and that means there are only 1 (or 0 of time machine disk gets full and deletes stuff) copies of this data and its no longer backed up.

So my question is, **if I put this "archive" data onto a RAID1 array containing 2 partitions, with each partition containing a copy of the data, is that considered a "backup" or no?**

The reason I am asking is because I feel like the duplicate partition sufficiently protects the data against user error (accidental deletion etc) to a degree that constitutes a "backup", and, even though both copies are on the same disk, the RAID array protects against total sudden disk failure.

In case this is not a good idea, **is there a better way of backing up this type of infrequently used (maybe accessed once or twice a month, if that) data?**

**Is there anything I am doing right or wrong with this kind of thinking?**

Clarification 1: For the archive RAID setup, im talking about two drives in a RAID array where the whole array (appearing as one disk on my computer) is broken into two partitions. I am not trying to RAID two partitions together, but merely store two copies of the archive data on the disk.

Comment: RAID only protect against MTBF, not fire, theft, lightning, malware, etc. go for physical separation.

Comment: @dandavis MTBF?

Comment: Mean Time Between Failure; the average expected lifespan of a product. Your drive WILL fail, as it has moving parts, be they kinetic or chemical. Any other problem is not helped by RAID.

Comment: A common saying is "RAID is not a backup". One misplaced command, a filesystem driver bug, or a ransomware infection and you are screwed. Your RAID1 setup will happily copy a command to format your filesystem to both drives. All redundant raid protects against is one of the drives going boom.

Comment: A lot of people seem to misinterpret this question as a raid-as-a-backup question.im asking if it would be considered *safe enough* if I was to MANUALLY duplicate the information yet have both copies on the same array

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you manually duplicate it and back it up somewhere else, then it doesn't matter if you are using RAID or not. RAID does not change the contents of the data.

Answer (score 4):

A backup is when you have two or more *independent* copies of something.  If one of the copies is destroyed, you can still use another copy.  For the purposes of backup, RAID 1 counts as just a single copy, since its two copies of the file are *dependent*: anything that happens to one will usually happen to the other as well.

If you've got a live copy of the data on your computer, and a second copy of the data on a removable RAID array stored somewhere else, you've got a backup: it takes two incidents (or one really large one) for you to lose all copies of the data.

From the description of your setup, your "backup array" doesn't count as a backup.  Since it's attached to your computer most of the time, it only protects you against hard-drive failure or accidental deletion.  It won't protect you against ransomware, or fire, or theft, or...

Your "archive array", on the other hand, can be used as a backup.  The partitioning you propose doesn't count (the only thing it protects against is user error), but if you store the hard drives making up the array in different places (eg. one drive at home, one at work) whenever the array's powered down, you've got your two independent copies.  You're still at risk any time the array's assembled and powered up, but it sounds like that won't be very often.

Comment: +1 for stressing that an effective backup has to be _independent_. Even though a RAID may be able to restore disk failure, an infection with Ransomware can easily kill your backup. Having such a setup is certainly a step in the right direction, but doesn't quite do the trick, if used as only measure against data loss.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! What would you recommend in terms of a) improving my backup array to protect against more (Like ransomware) and b) how could I use the archive array to best backup stuff that is no longer being stored on my main pc and therefore no longer part of my time machine process?

Answer (score -3):

RAID 1, or mirroring, is definately considered a backup in corp IT. I'm a little confused by your terms though. You can not "raid" 2 partitions on the same "disk". You can only Raid 2 partitions on 2 seperate physical drives (maybe there is some strange hack for this, but you can't make the drive heads write in 2 places at once).

For whatever it is worth, if you're on windows 10, there is a "file history" options that only backs up changes you've made. Simple, easy, built in.

...And then you can run Raid 0 for a big performance gain.

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity, with my raid setup im talking about two drives in a RAID array where the whole array (appearing as one disk on my computer) is broken into two partitions and each partition has a copy of the data (manual copy, as in ctrl-c, ctrl-v). i'l update the post with this

Comment: `RAID 1, or mirroring, is definately considered a backup in corp IT` this goes against what I've heard as RAID does not protect against user error, such as an accidentally deleted file, or hackers since all changes to the data are immediately made to both disks.

Comment: redundant != backup

Comment: Ok yes. There is some confusion about RAID here I think. RAID has numbers to deliminate what kind of "RAID" is being used. RAID "1" copies the data to 2 drives. It is literally a backup setting. RAID "0" copies the data across 2 disks which is nearly double speed, but no backup. If you are using Raid "0" on 2 paritions-- and one is a back up ...then if one disk dies completely: you lose everything (ignoring forensics, assuming full drive failure). If you want to use RAID, and want a back up, I have two options off top of my head: RAID 1. Or RAID 0 and backup to a cheap 3rd drive.

Comment: @DeveloperACE. RAID 1 should never be a full backup solution for an entire enterprise! But, that said, its sole purpose is to be a back up configuration to support failure tolerance.

Comment: @KrisBlouch from what I've read, RAID1 adds redundancy to protect against disk failure, but it is not a "backup". https://serverfault.com/questions/2888/why-is-raid-not-a-backup

Comment: @DeveloperACE. I don't want to split hairs here. I was answering at the level of the question. Multitiered backups with rolling deployments and etc are not in scope of original question! Also, I see you added some RAID numbers to the original question. Glad we can help! From the stance of original question; RAID 1 is a better "back up" than nothing. A backup partition on RAID 0 drive does not supports drive failures and is very risky. Back up to a 3rd disk.

Comment: @KrisBlouch those RAID numbers were there from the beginning. and, to clarify, I am ***NOT*** using any type of RAID for my main PC drives and calling that a backup, I am using RAID1 for my external drive arrays and the question is asking if two copies of the same data on a RAID1 array is considered safe enough contribute a "backup".

Comment: @DeveloperACE there were -no- Raid numbers. That's why I explained how that works. Come on bud.